# Magento - catalog layout

Tags: magento, layout, anchor

I have modified my magento catalog page using list.phtml by adding manufacturer name next to product name. Now this works well for all categories which have 'Anchor' set as No. It does not show the changes in categories where Anchor is set to yes. Could you please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code changes you made so that we can help you better

Answer (score 1):

The layout for anchor and non-anchor categories is different look here:

```
<catalog_category_default>
```

and

```
<catalog_category_layered>
```

in catalog.xml
Perhaps your template only uses the non anchor list.phtml and falls back to base/default for the anchor categories?

Comment: That could be correct because when the page loads, the manufacturer name appears and in a few seconds it falls back to possible the anchored template. However, I went into the base/default list.phtml and added the manufacturer, but still it won't show.

Comment: @user1844147 The behavior you describe sounds like javascript is being used to affect the view. Also, the `catalog_category_view` handle can be used for directives which should be processed for all category pages, though its directives will be processed *before* the `..._default` and `..._layered` handles.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I am not sure how to go ahead and solve this.

Comment: like @pzirkind said, in order to help further plz post your code and file location

Answer (score 0):

In list.phtml I added the manufacturer

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'),'name') ?> - <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a>
```